# What Resources Will I Free Up By Closing a CloseableHttpClient?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

According to the [Http Components tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html) I should `close()` a `CloseableHttpClient` to deallocate resources.

In my case, there would be benefits to simply creating the client when the application starts, and closing it when the application finishes. This would simplify heavily synchronized code that is required to ensure existing operations using the client have finished and new ones haven't become active yet.

If I leave my `CloseableHttpClient` object without closing it, for days at a time. What resources will I be hogging?

Comment: Just guessing, but from the link I'd say "functionality such as response content caching" and "the connection manager associated with it must be shut down" indicate two kinds of resources which may need to be released. However, what resources are actually allocated and held by a given implementation of an HttpClient is probably mostly at the discretion of the implementation itself.

Comment: Running on a Linux system you are likely to leave many connections in CLOSE_WAIT state and exhaust descriptors (too many open files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on `CloseableHttpClient` instance. Generally, `CloseableHttpClient#close` makes sure that the underlying connection pool is shut down and persistent connections kept alive are all closed out. Caching `CloseableHttpClient` instances bound to a persistent store may also clean up cache content.